# SpringMVC get 404 error

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, tomcat

I get 404 error in my browser, after I start my tomcat :

I type in `localhost:8080/mvc/hello` or `localhost:8080/mvc/hello.jsp`

[image]

But if I type in `localhost:8080`, it is normal, can access:

[image]

In my `springmvc-servlet.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"     
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"   
 xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd 
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd  
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.1.xsd"> 
    <!-- scan the package and the sub package --> 
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.ypd.springmvcdemo"/>
    <!-- don't handle the static resource -->
    <mvc:default-servlet-handler />
    <!-- if you use annotation you must configure following setting -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <!-- configure the InternalResourceViewResolver -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" id="internalResourceViewResolver">

        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />

        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

And in my `MVCController.java`:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/mvc")
public class MVCController {
    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    public String hello() {
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

In my `web.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">

    <!--configure the setting of springmvcDispatcherServlet and configure the mapping-->
   <servlet>
       <servlet-name>springmvc</servlet-name>
       <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
       <init-param>
           <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
           <param-value>classpath:springmvc-servlet.xml</param-value>
       </init-param>
   </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>springmvc</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

This is my page of `hello.jsp`:

[image]

(I am sorry about the `springmvc-servlet.xml`'s position, I have locate it to under the `resource` library)

**UPDATE - 1:**

I am so sorry about it, there is a mistake when I post this snapshot, in my issue project, the web folder has no blue dot on it.See my answer I find the issue with it.

Update image:

[image]

---

So, where is the mistake?

---

**EDIT**

My `hello.jsp`:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
Hello, world, jack loly!
</body>
</html>
```

---

**EDIT**

Logs looks like correct:

> [2017-03-20 03:06:48,255] Artifact SpringMVCDemo:war exploded: Server is not connected. Deploy is not available.
>   Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:51764', transport: 'socket'
>   20-Mar-2017 15:06:50.080 info [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version:        Apache Tomcat/9.0.0.M17
>   20-Mar-2017 15:06:50.085 info [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Jan 10 2017 20:59:20 UTC
>   20-Mar-2017 15:06:50.085 info [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:         9.0.0.0
>   20-Mar-2017 15:06:50.085 info [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Mac OS X
>   20-Mar-2017 15:06:50.088 info [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            10.12.2
>   20-Mar-2017 15:06:50.089 info [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          x86_64
>   20-Mar-2017 15:06:50.089 info [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
>   20-Mar-2017 15:06:50.089 info [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_121-b13
>   20-Mar-2017 15:06:50.089 info [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
>   20-Mar-2017 15:06:50.089 info [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         /Users/jack/Library/Caches/IntelliJIdea2016.3/tomcat/Tomcat_9_0_0_M17_SpringMVCDemo
>   20-Mar-2017 15:06:50.090 info [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         /Users/jack/Library/Tomcat9
>   20-Mar-2017 15:06:50.091 info [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/Users/jack/Library/Caches/IntelliJIdea2016.3/tomcat/Tomcat_9_0_0_M17_SpringMVCDemo/conf/logging.properties
>   20-Mar-2017 15:06:50.091 info [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
>   20-Mar-2017 15:06:50.091 info [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=127.0.0.1:51764,suspend=y,server=n
>   20-Mar-2017 15:06:50.091 info [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=
>   20-Mar-2017 15:06:50.092 info [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099
>   20-Mar-2017 15:06:50.093 info [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
>   20-Mar-2017 15:06:50.093 info [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
>   20-Mar-2017 15:06:50.093 info [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1
>   20-Mar-2017 15:06:50.093 info [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
>   20-Mar-2017 15:06:50.093 info [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
>   20-Mar-2017 15:06:50.093 info [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/Users/jack/Library/Caches/IntelliJIdea2016.3/tomcat/Tomcat_9_0_0_M17_SpringMVCDemo
>   20-Mar-2017 15:06:50.094 info [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/Users/jack/Library/Tomcat9
>   20-Mar-2017 15:06:50.094 info [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/Users/jack/Library/Tomcat9/temp
>   20-Mar-2017 15:06:50.094 info [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /Users/jack/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:.
>   20-Mar-2017 15:06:50.527 info [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
>   20-Mar-2017 15:06:50.560 info [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
>   20-Mar-2017 15:06:50.563 info [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
>   20-Mar-2017 15:06:50.565 info [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
>   20-Mar-2017 15:06:50.581 info [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 1455 ms
>   20-Mar-2017 15:06:50.709 info [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service Catalina
>   20-Mar-2017 15:06:50.709 info [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/9.0.0.M17
>   20-Mar-2017 15:06:50.745 info [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler [http-nio-8080]
>   20-Mar-2017 15:06:50.766 info [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler [ajp-nio-8009]
>   20-Mar-2017 15:06:50.769 info [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 187 ms
>   Connected to server
>   [2017-03-20 03:06:51,046] Artifact SpringMVCDemo:war exploded: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
>   [2017-03-20 03:06:51,751] Artifact SpringMVCDemo:war exploded: Artifact is deployed successfully
>   [2017-03-20 03:06:51,751] Artifact SpringMVCDemo:war exploded: Deploy took 705 milliseconds
>   20-Mar-2017 15:07:00.750 info [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /Users/jack/Library/Tomcat9/webapps/manager
>   20-Mar-2017 15:07:00.802 info [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /Users/jack/Library/Tomcat9/webapps/manager has finished in 52 ms

---

**EDIT**

My tomcat deployment config:
[image]

---

**EDIT -2**

[image]

Comment: Is there any  CSS or JS binded to JSP?

Comment: @srikanthr  No, there is not, it is a static page, like a html.

Comment: one thing that looks odd is the dirs. `src/main/webapp` is maven's convention. also, your spring xml usually goes in `src/main/resources`.

Comment: Did you check logs for errors?

Comment: @Philip YW, the logs looks like correct.

Comment: @roby what mean? friend? I have put the springmvc-servlet.xml in the `resources` folder.

Comment: your web directory should look like `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF`

Comment: @roby I try to rename the `web` to `webapp`, but I can not open the localhost , I use IntelliJ IDEA, the web is correct.

Comment: Put a breakpoint in the constructor of the dispatcher servlet. Also in the service method. Check they are getting hit then step through.

Comment: @roby, I tried. did not through the breakpoint.

Comment: That's what makes me think there is a problem with your directories. Maybe try to do it using WebApplicationInitializer instead of a web.xml

Comment: Here's your code, working (on my machine :) ). https://github.com/robobario/app

Tested against tomcat 7.0.47, launched out of intellij

Comment: @roby its strange, my friend , if convenient，leave your email, I send you my project.  I test your github demo, it is normal, but mine is not, strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last, I find the issue I was lost. See my question -> **UPDATE -1**

[image]

No blue dot on it means Web Source Dictory is incorrect. See below image I find the issue.

[image]

So I delete the red directory, and then re-choose the web directory:

[image]

Then in my project, I can see the blue dot on web directory now:

[image]

And then I restart tomcat, I success:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Put your springmvc-servlet.xml file in the WEB-INF and change lines of web.xml

```
<init-param>
       <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
       <param-value>classpath:springmvc-servlet.xml</param-value>
</init-param>
```

To

```
<init-param>
       <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
       <param-value>/WEB-INF/springmvc-servlet.xml</param-value>
</init-param>
```

Comment: Did you check  whether your hello() method is called or not?

Comment: I use IntenliJ IDEA, and the springmvc-servlet.xml should put in the resources librariy, right?

Comment: I tried, get the same error, and more the `springmvc-servlet.xml` cannot resolved.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of things to notice.

1. No project name specified in url

> URL should be : `http://localhost:8080/SpringMVCDemo/mvc/hello`

2. Why are you mentioning two `RequestMapping(mvc,hello)` for only one page.You can remove `@RequestMapping(value="/mvc")` and keep `@RequestMapping("/hello")` on `hello()` method.

**Update:**

add `load-on-startup` in `web.xml`

```
<servlet>
       <servlet-name>springmvc</servlet-name>
       <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
       <init-param>
           <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
           <param-value>classpath:springmvc-servlet.xml</param-value>
       </init-param>
     <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>
```

Comment: Friend, for 1) I config my tomcat deployment like my `EDIT`, you can see my update.  for 2) I tried annotate the `@RequestMapping(value="/mvc")`, and restart my tomcat, but useless.

Comment: @qg_java remove the @RequestMapping(value="/mvc") and restart and check...and one more thing, see console by inspect element in browser and let me know if there are any errors

Comment: Friend,  I get `HTTP Status 404 -` if I remove the `@RequestMapping(value="/mvc")` then type in `http://localhost:8080/SpringMVCDemo/mvc/hello` in my safari.

Comment: I'm sorry about that, but the `http://localhost:8080/SpringMVCDemo/hello` is 404 too.

Comment: Or leave your email, I send my project to you.

Comment: @qg_java are you sure that your context name of project is SpringMVCDemo?? and have you checked the console in browser by inpsect element in CHROME for errors??

Comment: see my `EIDT -2`.

Comment: @qg_java move your sprinmvc-servlet.xml to WEB-INF folder....beside web.xml

Comment: Still useless, friend, did you get my code from e-mail ?

Comment: I think it is a context root config problem. Perhaps you can paste the log after you call the webpage.

Comment: @qg_java yup...but its a maven project,my environment has some problem with maven repo....wait i will convert that to normal tomcat project and see

Answer (score 0):

I think your tomcat deployment configuration is not all okay. your application context should be the context from where you are going to load your application and tell tomcat to dispatch all request within that context.

e.g. your **Application Context:** could be `/helloApp`. Now when you will start tomcat, your application would be loaded at `localhost:8080/helloApp/`. And this is your application root context. Now if you hit at `localhost:8080/helloApp/mvc/hello`, you are expected to see your content.

Comment: I tried to config the tomcat deployment Application Context to : `/SpringMVCDemo`, but after I restart my tomcat, and type `http://localhost:8080/SpringMVCDemo/mvc/hello` in safari, still get 404.

Comment: Rather than just restarting the tomcat, please delete the **target** folder and rebuild your project then restart tomcat, so that tomcat gets the updated build of your application. In other words, I find you codes okay, it should run as it is expected.